# React JS: I have an odd looking dependency in my package.json file

Tags: reactjs

I have no idea how this got added, anyone knows anything about this and if it's not needed how Do I remove it?

**"-": "0.0.1"**

Here is a complete list of dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.4.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.13.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.4",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look to be anything. It's just composed of an `index.js` whose contents are, in full:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = null;
```

It's not doing any harm (yet), but it's junk.

If you installed it accidentally, remove it.

If something accidentally changed its configuration to depend on it, change the configuration back.

One might have installed it accidentally by typing

```
npm install -
```

instead of passing a flag.